# Python Convert Decimal Fixed Point List to Radians

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of decimal fixed point numbers:

```
latitude = Places.query.with_entities(Places.latitude).all()
result = []
for i in range(len(latitude)):
    result.append(latitude[i][0])
print result
```

The output of latitude is [this](https://pastebin.com/zu2QBs3d)
I wanted to map them to Radians. So, I did this:

```
lat_ = map(lambda i: radians(i), result)
```

But got an error`TypeError: a float` is required

I want to know what is the correct way to do this operation. `

**Edit**

Now the result looks like this:

```
[28.633, 29.333,...]
```

And error is:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: Do you neeed the angle as float or as Decimal?

Comment: I need it as float

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Assuming the function `radians` is from math module your code produces `_lat = [1.3476856525247056, 1.3482668471656196, 1.3476856525247056, 1.3476856525247056, 1.3473941825396225, 1.3476856525247056]` in my interpreter (Python 2.7).

Comment: Even when I run the script I get the output same as you. Wait let me post the full code

Comment: @Bill check now

Comment: That's a big data set.  I would get it working on a few items first (say 5 to 10) and if it works on that then it is probably an error or inconsistency in your data set, not the code.

Comment: The data set you posted is a list of dictionaries.  That is the problem.

Comment: in what sort of context is converting a latitude to radian useful?

Comment: finding distance between lat and long. Haversine function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rads = [x['latitude'] for x in result]
_lat = map(lambda i: radians(i), rads)
```

Comment: TypeError: a float is required. That what I am getting. I think the query is file the problem is with my sqlalchemy query

Comment: What if I put few None values in the output of rads. Then how can i map rads to radians

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the radians function from the maths module expects an input of type float, not of type Decimal. You'll have to convert the values to float first:

```
lat_ = map(lambda i: radians(float(i)), result)
```

Comment: Good guess.  But try testing this: `radians(Decimal("90"))`

Answer (score 1):

```
from decimal import *

from math import radians

result = [Decimal('77.216700'), Decimal('77.250000'), Decimal('77.216700'), Decimal('77.216700'), Decimal('77.200000'), Decimal('77.216700')]

lat_ = map(lambda i: radians(float(i)), result)

# [1.3476856525247056, 1.3482668471656196, 1.3476856525247056,
#  1.3476856525247056, 1.3473941825396225, 1.3476856525247056]
```