# Convert a dictionary of type str to float Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, python-2.7

There is something strange going on when I try to query PostgreSQL database and retrieve values of only one column and then converting it to JSON:

```
latitude = Places.query.with_entities(Places.latitude).all()
longitude = Places.query.with_entities(Places.longitude).all()
user_schema = UserSchema(many=True, strict = True)
print user_schema
output = user_schema.dump(latitude).data

output = json.dumps([dict(r) for r in output], default=alchemyencoder)
print output         #[{"latitude": 28.6333}, {"latitude": 28.6333},...]
print type(output)   #<type 'str'>
```

Although it seems that the result of output is a list of dictionaries and can be iterated to do operations but then in the process of iterating over this dict I was getting errors:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

So, I check the `type(output)` and it gives me `str` which is why?

Also, When I try to convert it to a `float` or `int` using

```
output = float(output)
```

I get an error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: [{"latitude": 28.6333}, {"latitude": 28.6333},....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want a string, you should not be using `json.dumps()` .  How about:

#### Code:

```
[x["latitude"] for x in output]
```

#### Test Code:

```
latitude = Places.query.with_entities(Places.latitude).all()
longitude = Places.query.with_entities(Places.longitude).all()
user_schema = UserSchema(many=True, strict = True)
print user_schema
output = user_schema.dump(latitude).data

print([x["latitude"] for x in output])
```

Comment: now my output is type list. `[28.63, 28.65, .....]` and when I try this `_lat = map(lambda i: radians(i), rads)` i got `TypeError: a float is required`. Can you tell what is wrong

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question.  Be careful about describing exactly your current situation.

Comment: Here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723289/python-convert-decimal-fixed-point-list-to-radians?noredirect=1#comment84454087_48723289

Comment: I do not have your data.  So, I can not say.  Again I suggest asking a new question.  Show the exact data you are trying to convert. From the above link show exactly what is in `rads`...

Comment: If you like, leave a link here if you want to be sure I see it.

Comment: I have edited the code on above link. Please see. Both the questions are related . The list what is got here is now to be mapped to radians. It would be helpful if can just see the question